# IDFA Advertising identifier appstore guideline

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

I am using one third party library  which has advertising identifier,Unfortunately they don't provide the source code so I can't remove IDFA part of code, So I wanted to ask that  my app will get approved if I am not displaying any ad on my application  but having the advertising identifier code in my app  ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, it won't get approved if you are not displaying ads

Comment: To add to @Paulw11 answer you will need to specify what the IDFA is used when you submit your app. And you wil have to confirm that you are aware that Apple might reject your app if they find out that the IDFA is not used according to the review guidelines.